# Write value to GPIO on android

Tags: android, linux, unix, adb, gpio

Using `adb`, I'm having trouble setting the value of a GPIO pin high on my android device. There is no problem changing the direction from in to out and back again yet whenever I try to write the value it does not seem to change. This can be seen here:

`root@android:/sys/class/gpio # ls
export 
gpio101 
gpio112 
gpiochip0 
gpiochip107 
gpiochip16 
gpiochip43
gpiochip68 
gpiochip95 
unexport 
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # su -c echo in  > gpio101/direction
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # cat gpio101/direction 
in 
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # su -c echo out > gpio101/direction
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # cat gpio101/direction
out 
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # su -c echo 1 > gpio101/value
root@android:/sys/class/gpio # cat  gpio101/value 
0`

At first I thought the pin might be a dedicated input but exporting other GPIO pins I saw that whether they initially had a direction of in or out, the value was always 0 and could not be changed.

Why can't I write it and what should I do?